# Making a DIV expand with content as opposed to scroll

Tags: html, css, overflow

Hey I am developing a website and I have hit a problem early on I added overflow:auto; to all of my main classes .header .content .footer because I was having a few background and ribbon errors which it cleaned right up.

However I have recently discovered that because of this attribute the .content class when it has enough content scrolls instead of continuing to expand (I have tried height:auto; and height:100%;) if I disable overflow:auto; the content continues to on top of my .footer and my ribbons and backgrounds also mess up.

I am not sure if I can force the div to expand or if I have to rework all my CSS?

It is not a huge problem and the webpage remains functional with scrolling but surely there is a work around.

}

```
.Header
{
width:  100%;
overflow: auto;
padding-top: 80px;
background: rgb(45, 55, 60);
}

.Content
{
width:  100%;
overflow: auto;
padding-top: 50px;
background: rgb(255, 250, 240);
}

 .Footer
{
width:  100%;
overflow: auto;
padding-top: 30px;
background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}
```

It could also be then content I suppose but I am really at a loss have been searching for past 4 hours thought it might be wise to post.

Comment: Can you also post your HTML? That will help with understanding what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `overflow: auto;` from all your classes. They should expand with what is inside them on their own.

http://jsfiddle.net/BGLMJ/4/